# Keep $OLDPWD between Shell Sessions

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc, alias

Often, I'm leaving the terminal and the next day run it again. Then I want to be able to quickly go back to the last working directory.

I would like to do this using `cd -` as usual. But `$OLDPWD` is not kept between terminal sessions.

So I added an alias for `exit` to write `pwd` to a file and read it on the next start.

```
alias exit='pwd > ~/.lwd && exit;'
test -f ~/.lwd && export OLDPWD=`head -1 ~/.lwd`
```

That works perfectly for `exit`.

How can I create the same alias (or make a trap) for `Ctrl+D` ?

Comment: alias is for command, ctrl-d isn't a command but a keyboard combo

Comment: Sure I know. But has the same effect in this case: Exit the terminal. And as it is faster I tend to use it more often.

Comment: Your main object is to open the terminal on the last `cd`ed directory, right? Then [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32508/how-can-i-open-a-new-terminal-in-the-same-directory-of-the-last-used-one-from-a) might be of some help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trap` to add a handler for `EXIT`:

```
trap 'pwd > ~/.lwd' EXIT
```

This should handle both the `exit` command and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. The rest, you can do as with the alias.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Anwar](https://askubuntu.com/users/61218/anwar) to lead me in the right direction. [This post from the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145863) helped me.

I created a file `~/.bash_logout` with following content:

```
echo "$PWD" > ~/.lwd
```

In `~/.bashrc` I added:

```
test -f ~/.lwd && export OLDPWD=`head -1 ~/.lwd`
```

This works for `exit` **and** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for gnome-terminal and for ssh connections.

Comment: This works *if* you're using a login shell. GNOME Terminal does not, by default, so you must have enabled it in the preferences.

Comment: I did not ... or I don't know. "Run command as a login shell" in profile settings is unticked.

Comment: Then you might want to double check your tests. [`~/.bash_logout` is only run for login shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoked-as-an-interactive-login-shell_002c-or-with-_002d_002dlogin) (Also, remember to quote `$PWD`: `echo "$PWD" > ...`)